# Batch rename with command line

Tags: command-line, rename, mv

I have some files: `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and I would like to rename them like this: `file1.something.txt` and `file2.something.txt`
I looked for some similar questions and I come up with this:

```
for i in file*.txt; do echo  mv $i file*.something.txt; done
```

but unfortunately the output is:

```
mv file1.txt file*.something.txt

mv file2.txt file*.something.txt
```

and therefore only 1 file is created.
Could please somebody help?
(I am using a macbook air, I am not sure if this is relevant)
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
rename -n 's/\.txt/something.txt' *
```

(remove -n switch when your tests are OK)

[image: warning]
 **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

and not containing:

```
ELF
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.